# Delete a windows group in Active Directory

Tags: active-directory, scripting, powershell

I am doing a cleanup of some AD groups that are no longer used. One of the AD groups I could not delete because it seems that a member has this group set as the primary group (which I assume someone did by accident). Is there an easy way to find out who has this group set as primary?

Answer (score 9):

You'll need to get the primaryGroupToken value of the group in question:

1. Use adsiedit to examine the group you want to get delete.  Make note of the primaryGroupToken attribute's value.
2. Create a Saved Query in Active Directory Users and Computers using the following "Custom Search" where XXX= the value you found for primaryGroupToken:

   (&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)(primaryGroupID=XXX))
3. Refresh the query to see who shows up

Alternatively - If all users are expected to be members of Domain Users as their primary group, just define the query using(513 is the typical value for Domain Users):

```
(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)(!primaryGroupID=513))
```

Additional Links:

http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;321360
http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;297951

Great Question!

Answer (score 2):

Just by giving the privileges

To delete windows group in Active directory

1. Open notepad
2. Copy and paste below text to notepad
3. Save the file with .ps1 extension.

## ---------- SCRIPT STARTS HERE--------------

## VERSION 2

## 4/19/2010

## script to modify termed users

## 1.pull termed users from CSV

## remove user group membership

## 2.Clear Manager property

## 3.Hide from GAL

## 4.move to disabed OU

## 5.rename csv to completed date, move to completed

$groupmembershiplog="c:\removeADAttributes\group_membership_log.csv"
$erroractionpreference = "SilentlyContinue"
$termfile=Test-Path -Path "C:\removeADAttributes\termed_employees.csv"
If ($termfile -eq "True") {
$inputcsv="C:\removeADAttributes\termed_employees.csv"
$completeddir="C:\removeADAttributes\completed\"
$date=Get-Date -format d

import-CSV $inputcsv | foreach-object {
$username=$_.account

## export groups to file

$groups=(Get-QADUser $username).memberof
Add-Content $groupmembershiplog $username","$groups

## remove groups

$groups | Get-QADGroup | where {$_.name -ne "domain users"} | Remove-QADGroupMember -Member $name
Set-QADUser -Identity $username -objectattributes @{"Manager"="$null"}
$currentuser=Get-QADUser -Identity $username -SizeLimit 1
$currentOU=$currentuser.parentcontainer
$currentOU = $currentOU.Split('/')
$currentOU = $currentOU[1]
Move-QADObject -identity $username -NewParentContainer "domainname.com/$ou/Disabled Accounts"
}

import-CSV $inputcsv | foreach-object {
$username=$*.account
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.Exchange.Management.PowerShell.Admin
Set-Mailbox -Identity $username -HiddenFromAddressListsEnabled $true
}
import-CSV $inputcsv | foreach-object {
$username=$*.account
Add-Content "C:\removeADAttributes\removeADAttributes_log.csv" $date","$username
}

Move-Item $inputcsv -Destination $completeddir
$todaydate=$date.replace("/","_")
$newfilename=$todaydate+".csv"
Rename-Item "C:\removeADAttributes\completed\termed_employees.csv" -NewName $newfilename

}
else {
$date=Get-Date -format d
Add-Content "C:\removeADAttributes\removeADAttributes_log.csv" $date",no term user, no term user"
exit
}

## ---------- SCRIPT ENDSS HERE------------

Hope this scripts will be useful for you

Answer (score -2):

I know this is a old thread but for people having this same issue. If you are removing the group anyways there is a easier method.

- Open the group and go to the members tab.
- Select all the users
- Remove the users.
- One of the users that are left has the group as the primary. For me it was the user with the lowest alphabetical name.
- Change the primary group for that user
- Delete group or repeat to find other users with this group as the primary.

Comment: this can prove unacceptably time-consuming. There are scripting\automated ways of doing this as well.